# Can't get horizontal alignment to work in only one case

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have these styles set up:

```
var titleStyle = {};
titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 20;
titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = true;
titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;

var sectionStyle = {};
sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = true;
sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
```

This centers the title:

```
var docTitle = noteBody.appendParagraph(title);
docTitle.setAttributes(titleStyle);
```

This does not center the section header!

```
var nextHeader = noteBody.appendTable(headerTable);
nextHeader.setAttributes(sectionStyle);
```

But it DOES do all the other things - size, bold, underline, etc. Just not center!! What could I be missing? Full script below

```
  var date = new Date();
    var zone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, zone, 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm a');
  var docName = "title here - " + formattedDate;
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(docName);
  var docFiles = DriveApp.getFilesByName(docName);
  var docFile = docFiles.next();
  var noteBody = doc.getBody();
  var document = [];

/** styles */
var titleStyle = {};
titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 20;
titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = true;
titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;

var sectionStyle = {};
sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = true;
sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;

var headerStyle = {};
headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 16;
headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = false;

var gridStyle = {};
gridStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 13;
gridStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
gridStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = true;

var tableStyle = {};
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = false;

function autoPDF() {
  
  //find or create folder
  var docFolders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("AutoPDF");
  if (docFolders.hasNext()){var docFolder = docFolders.next()}
  else {var docFolder = DriveApp.createFolder("AutoPDF")};
  docFile.moveTo(docFolder);


  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var title = form.getTitle();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var responseSet = form.getResponses();
  var lastResponse = responseSet.length - 1;
  var itemResponse = responseSet[lastResponse].getItemResponses(); //this is the set of responses for the most recent submission

  var table = [];

  title = title + '\n';
  var docTitle = noteBody.appendParagraph(title);
  docTitle.setAttributes(titleStyle);
    
  var j = 0;
  for (i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    var itemType = items[i].getType();
    var itemTitle = items[i].getTitle();

    //question items
    if (itemType != 'IMAGE' &&
        itemType != 'PAGE_BREAK' &&
        itemType != 'SECTION_HEADER' &&
        itemType != 'VIDEO'         )
      {


        //additional step needed for multiple answer options - turn array into string        
        if (itemType == 'CHECKBOX_GRID'){
          
          table.push(['\n' + itemTitle.toUpperCase()]); //add grid item title
          
          var cgItem = items[i].asCheckboxGridItem();
          var answerRow = [];
          var row = cgItem.getRows();
          var numRows = cgItem.getRows().length;
          var cgResponse = itemResponse[j].getResponse();
          for(n=0; n<numRows; n++){
            var rowTitle = "     " + row[n].toString();
            if (cgResponse[n] == null) {cgResponse[n] = "[no answer]";}
            var answers = cgResponse[n].toString();
            answerRow = [rowTitle, answers];
            table.push(answerRow)
          }
        }
        
       else if (itemType == 'GRID') {
          
          table.push(['\n' + itemTitle.toUpperCase()]); //add grid item title
          
          var gItem = items[i].asGridItem();
          var answerRow = [];
          var row = gItem.getRows();
          var numRows = gItem.getRows().length;
          var gResponse = itemResponse[j].getResponse();
          for(n=0; n<numRows; n++){
            var rowTitle = "     " + row[n].toString();
            if (gResponse[n] == null) {gResponse[n] = "[no answer]";}
            var answers = gResponse[n].toString();
            answerRow = [rowTitle, answers];
            table.push(answerRow)
          }
        } 

        else {
          
          var tableRow = [itemTitle, itemResponse[j].getResponse()]; //itemResponse[j] is the response to question #j (from the most recent answer set) 
            
          //turning response from array into string?
          var responseString = "";  
          for (m=1; m<tableRow.length; m++){
            responseString = responseString + tableRow[m];
            if (m<tableRow.length-1) {responseString = responseString + ", ";} //if it's the last one don't add this
          }
          tableRow = [itemTitle, responseString];
          table.push(tableRow);
        }
        
        j++;
      }
    
    //layout items
    else if (itemType == 'SECTION_HEADER' || itemType == 'PAGE_BREAK'){
      addToDoc(table);
      
      var headerTable = [];
      headerTable.push([items[i].getTitle()]);

      var nextHeader = noteBody.appendTable(headerTable);
      nextHeader.setAttributes(sectionStyle);

      //table style
      nextHeader.setAttributes(sectionStyle); /////HERE
      nextHeader.setBorderWidth(0);
      if (i<items.length-1) {table = []}; //clear for a restart if there are more items
    }
  }
  
  addToDoc(table); //add last table - doesn't end with layout item


  /** create PDF from doc and move it to new folder */
  var pdfBlob = docFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  var newPDF = docFolder.createFile(pdfBlob);
  newPDF.setName(title + " - " + formattedDate);
  docFile.setTrashed(true);

}

function addToDoc(table){
  var nextTable = noteBody.appendTable(table);
  nextTable.setAttributes(tableStyle);
  nextTable.setBorderWidth(0);
  nextTable.setColumnWidth(0, 200);
  nextTable.setColumnWidth(1, 300);
}
```

Comment: When I tested your showing script to the sample paragraphs, it seemed that both attributes worked. So, in this case, it is required to correctly replicate your situation of `But it DOES do all the other things - size, bold, underline, etc. Just not center!!`. Can you provide detailed information for correctly replicating your current situation? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: The question is why my sections, using sectionStyle, are not centering, but my titles are? Should I post the entire code here?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that in your situation, correctly replicating your situation will help understand the issue of your current situation. So, I asked about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue. About `Should I post the entire code here?`, I do not know your script. So, I'm not sure whether your whole script directly leads to the reason for your current issue. I apologize for this. But, if your script can be used for replicating your situation, can you provide it?

Comment: I added the whole code. The line where I try to setAttributes is marked off with ////HERE. Thanks for your willingness to help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply and provided script, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. In this case, it supposes that your showing script worked fine. Please be careful about this. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your showing script, I could notice that your actual question is related to the table cell. From `The line where I try to setAttributes is marked off with ////HERE.`, in this case, how about the following modification? In the case of the cell value, the paragraph is used.

Please modify your showing script as follows.

#### From:

```
var headerTable = [];
headerTable.push([items[i].getTitle()]);

var nextHeader = noteBody.appendTable(headerTable);
nextHeader.setAttributes(sectionStyle);
```

#### To:

```
var headerTable = [];
headerTable.push([items[i].getTitle()]);

var nextHeader = noteBody.appendTable(headerTable);

// Added
nextHeader.getCell(0, 0).getChild(0).asParagraph().setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

nextHeader.setAttributes(sectionStyle);
```

or

```
var headerTable = [];
headerTable.push([items[i].getTitle()]);

var nextHeader = noteBody.appendTable(headerTable);

// Modified
// nextHeader.setAttributes(sectionStyle);
nextHeader.getCell(0, 0).getChild(0).asParagraph().setAttributes(sectionStyle);
```

- By this modification, the alignment of the cell value of `items[i].getTitle()` is set as the center.

#### Note:

- In this sample, it supposes that your showing script works fine. Please be careful about this.
- Unfortunately, I do not know your actual situation. So, I cannot test your whole script. But, when I tested a simple sample script using your showing script, I confirmed that the modified script worked. The following script is a simple sample script for testing. When this script is run, a new Google Document is created. When you open it, you can see that the text of "sample value" is aligned as the center.

```js
function sample() {
  const noteBody = DocumentApp.create("sample").getBody();


  // This is from your showing script.
  var sectionStyle = {};
  sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
  sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
  sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = true;
  sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;

  // This is from your showing script.
  var tableStyle = {};
  tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
  tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
  tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = false;

  // Below script is from your showing script.
  var headerTable = [];
  headerTable.push(["sample value"]); // This is a sample value.
  var nextHeader = noteBody.appendTable(headerTable);
  nextHeader.getCell(0, 0).getChild(0).asParagraph().setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  nextHeader.setAttributes(sectionStyle);
  nextHeader.setBorderWidth(0);
}
```

or

```js
function sample() {
  const noteBody = DocumentApp.create("sample").getBody();


  // This is from your showing script.
  var sectionStyle = {};
  sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
  sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
  sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = true;
  sectionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;

  // This is from your showing script.
  var tableStyle = {};
  tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
  tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
  tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = false;

  // Below script is from your showing script.
  var headerTable = [];
  headerTable.push(["sample value"]); // This is a sample value.
  var nextHeader = noteBody.appendTable(headerTable);
  nextHeader.getCell(0, 0).getChild(0).asParagraph().setAttributes(sectionStyle);
  nextHeader.setBorderWidth(0);
}
```

#### References:

- [setAlignment(alignment) of Class Paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment))
- [setAttributes(attributes)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setattributesattributes)